# Add byte array inside a json object using java

Tags: java, json

I have below situation. It needs to be implemented in Java.

1. Take input from a text file, convert the content into a byte array.
2. Use the above byte array as a part of a JSON object , create a .json file

For point1, i have done something like this.

```
  InputStream is = new ClassPathresource("file.txt").getInputStream();
  byte[] ip =  IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

For point2, my Json file (containing json object), should look like below.

```
  {
   "name": "xyz",
   "address: "address here",
   "ipdata": ""
  }
```

The **ipdata** should contain the byte array created in step 1.

How can i create a json object with the byte array created in step 1 as a part of it ? And then write the entire content to a separate .json file ?

Also is the byte array conversion done in step1 an optimum way, or do we need to use any other API(may be to take care of encoding)?Please suggest.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Common way to include binary data in JSON is to encode it as a Base 64 string. Did the person who assigned this task give any indication that's what they want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reading a JSON string from file and want to write it back to a new json file you dont need the JSON Object conversion in-between. Just convert the byte[] to String as

`String ips = new String(ip);`

Now create a `JSON` Object with the data you want to write to the new file. And then you can write the data to file using `FileWriter`. PFB the code-

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "xyz");
obj.put("address", "address here");
obj.put("ipdata", ips);
try(FileWriter fileWriter =
    new FileWriter("newFileName.json") ){
    fileWriter.write(obj.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you do this, it's good practice to specify the character encoding when creating the String. Also, steer clear of FileWriter since it always uses the platform default character encoding. Instead, wrap a FileOutputStream in an OutputStreamWriter (which takes the encoding as a constructor argument).

Comment: The json i am creating is used to send a request to a webservice. The webservice accepts input in form of byte array. So the conversion to String will not help i guess. Any other way to add the byte array as is in the JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can simply convert the byte array ip using `ip.toString()`
2. Or if you know the encoding you can use `ipString = new String(ip, "UTF8")`

And then take that string to add to your json object.

Comment: Regarding, `ip.toString()` -- the `toString()` method of an array just prints the element type and object ID, like: `"[B@101df177"`.  But I guess that's one way to "include the byte array in the JSON object" :-D

Comment: The json i am creating is used to send a request to a webservice. The webservice accepts input in form of byte array. So the conversion to String will not help i guess. Any other way to add the byte array as is in the JSON object?